# Automatic1111 not working again for M1 users

Tags: webserver, artificial-intelligence, apple-m1, stable-diffusion

https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Installation-on-Apple-Silicon

After some recent updates to Automatic1111's Web-Ui I can't get the webserver to start again. I'm hoping that someone here might have figured it out. I'm stuck in a loop of modules not found errors and the like, Is anyone in the same boat?

Something that looks like this when I try to run the script to start the webserver.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/wesley/Documents/stable-diffusion-webui/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.py", line 7, in

from fastapi import FastAPI

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'

(web-ui) wesley@Wesleys-MacBook-Air stable-diffusion-webui %

I have tried pip and conda installing every one of these types of errors that come up but no dice.

I have tried pip and conda installing every one of these types of errors that come up but no dice.
I've tried cleaning my env, tried trashing it all and reinstalling it. Tried running scripts found in the issues section on the repro. https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+m1

Comment: Automatic1111 is a GitHub username. See https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111 and [Why AUTOMATIC1111 is named like this?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/179/12)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same issue a while ago. And I resolved it by pip installing the missing components but, in order for this procedure to work, I had to, first, activate the LDM virtua environment, which is the one that 1111 uses.